AttributeError: partially initialized module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_csv'
Quiero leer un archivo en vsc importando pandas y numpy, éste es mi código:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

archivo = pd.read_csv("C:\\9python\\dataset.csv")**

y me sale el siguiente error:
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_csv' (most likely due to a circular import)


El problema es por que tienes definido el nombre de tu archivo .py con este nombre csv.py y hace que pandas confunda acerca de qué importar.

Solución
Cambia el nombre del archivo .py por otro nombre. Por ejemplo a test.py.


Tenia instalada dos versiones diferentes de python por lo que pandas se volvía loco y creo que estaba instalado en la otra versión. Gracias por tener el cuenta el nombre y formato del archivo  Xavier Llauca

Para aclarar, este error ocurre porque pandas normalmente importa el modulo csv (de la biblioteca estándar de Python). Como en este caso se nombra el escript principal csv.py, pandas importa éste módulo en vez de csv de la stdlib (porque los módulos del CWD tienen prefrencia). Como tu modulo csv a la vez importa a pandas; ¡bumm! import circular. Moraleja, jamás debes nombrar tus módulos igual que un modulo de la stdlib o de algún paquete externo instalado, como numpy.py. Si el problema fuera tener pandas instalado en otro entorno/venv el error no sería este, sino un ModuleNotFoundError.
